# Western musical instruments that can be played with one hand

Tags: instruments, string-instruments, percussion, physical-limitations

https://www.google.com/search?q=western+musical+instruments

Will it be very few western musical instruments that can be played by human beings with one hand only?

Example : Mouth organ.

Comment: it's an interesting question, but it needs a lot more research.

Comment: Is mouth organ another term for harmonica? Or melodica? Any keyboard instrument can be played with one hand.

Comment: Paul Wittgenstein famously played the piano with one hand only since he lost his right arm during the First World War.  He commissioned many works for this purpose from famous composers.  Many percussion instruments can be played with one hand - tubular bells, castanets, maracas, tam tam, etc.

Comment: Are feet allowed?

Comment: Do you accept being able to play an instrument within a limited but still useful range, like e.g. keyboard instruments

Comment: Lots of percussion instruments can be played one-handed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - mouth organ = harmonica = 'harp'. No, not the harp one needs to wear in order to play it!

Comment: Possible better question - what instruments **cannot** be played properly with only one hand?

Comment: Do you mean the "country and western" tag? You could crack a whip one-handed (a-la the Blues Brothers version of Theme from Rawhide)?

Comment: @Tim Yeah, I know about "harp", that's what I usually call them (been a blue harp player for decades). Just never heard "mouth organ" before.

Comment: Check out Ben Clements: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFs0xlpGnl8&list=RDZFs0xlpGnl8&start_radio=1&t=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bugles are one-handed. Trumpets, tenor and French horns would be playable to *some* extent. The pipe of a pipe and tabor! Flexatones are lovely things. I've seen virtuoso bass guitarists play whole pieces with one hand.

At [OHMI](https://www.ohmi.org.uk/instruments.html) (One handed musical Instruments) there are all kinds of instruments and *adapted* instruments. The one-handed clarinets and Chapman Sticks look good. They also have supports for the trumpet and trombone.

Answer (score 3):

Keyboard instruments such as piano, plucking instruments such as harp, .... many can be played with one hand only.

Answer (score 2):

Drums. Rick Allen, the drummer with Def Leppard, lost an arm in a car crash may years ago, but has carried on ever since (using an adapted kit, but nothing that any drummer couldn't put together using midi)

Answer (score 1):

Three hole pipe. Usually used in conjunction with a drum to form the pipe and tabor, but the pipe part is a one-hander

Comment: I think that's the pipe I mentioned above. Do you play it btw?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for the duplication. And yes I do play, not very much but it gets a run out occasionally